# Are the send and receive methods of sf::UdpSocket threadsafe?

Tags: c++, sockets, thread-safety, sfml

I have a NetworkDevice class that runs an `std::thread` to queue all incoming packets. While doing this I also want to send Packets on the same `sf::UdpSocket`.
I cant find any Information about though, about whether the send & receive methods of `sf::UdpSocket` are threadsafe.

The class looks something like that:

```
class NetworkDevice
{
   std::thread m_Thread;
   std::mutex m_Mtx;
   bool isRunning;
   sf::UdpSocket m_Socket;
   std::deque<std::pair<Packet, Connection>> m_Packets;

   void listenUdp()
   {
      while(isRunning)
      {
      // Do some stuff
      m_Socket.receive(packet, remoteAddress, remotePort);
      m_Mtx.lock();
      m_Packets.push_back(std::make_pair(packet, Connection(remoteAddress, remotePort)));
      m_Mtx.unlock();
      // Do some stuff
      }
   }

   void startThread();
   {
      isRunning = true;
      m_Thread = std::thread([this](){listenUdp();});
   }

   void sendPacket(Packet& packet, Connection& connection);
   {
      m_Socket.send(packet, connection.address, connection.port);
   }

   void update(std::deque<std::pair<Packet, Connection>>& packets)
   {
      m_Mtx.lock();
      packets = m_Packets;
      m_Mtx.unlock();
   }
};
```

**Will I have any unexpected effects when the `sf::UdpSocket::send` and `sf::UdpSocket::receive` methods are working simultaneouly?**

And If so should I rather:

1. Have a mutex that gets locked before executing above named methods?
2. Have a second socket just for sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer for the package you're using, but at the operating system level these methods are atomic and therefore thread-safe. You can invoke them from multiple threads at the same time. Simultaneous sends and receives will proceed independently; simultaneous sends will happen atomically in some undefined order; and simultaneous receives will also happen atomically in some undefined order.

Unless the package has serious implementation peculiarities I would expect it also to be be thread-safe: there's no inherent reason why it can't be. You certainly don't need separate sockets for sending and receiving. This is just wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

As I couldnt find any evidence that `sf::UdpSocket::Send` & `sf::UdpSocket::receive` are threadsafe, I assume they are not.